# Group By in Spark with Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no space for new record

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to implement my Hive query codes in spark SQL.
(I'm pretty sure those work in Hive but I don't know why spark throw me an error.)

I have quite a big table which is generated from Hive:

```scala
val df= spark.sql("select ... from a join b ... group by d...")
```

When I show the df or output it into Hive, it works fine

```scala
df.show()
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("tableName")
```

But, when I do this:

```scala
val df2 = df.groupBy("colA").agg(sum("colB"))
df2.show()
//or
df2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("tableDF2")
```

There is an error after running job for long time

```
17/06/14 06:39:50 WARN RowBasedKeyValueBatch: Calling spill() on 

RowBasedKeyValueBatch. Will not spill but return 0.
17/06/14 06:39:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 62.0 (TID 1982)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no space for new record
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeInMemorySorter.insertRecord(UnsafeInMemorySorter.java:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeKVExternalSorter.<init>(UnsafeKVExternalSorter.java:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.destructAndCreateExternalSorter(UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.java:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/06/14 06:39:50 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 62.0 (TID 1982, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no space for new record
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeInMemorySorter.insertRecord(UnsafeInMemorySorter.java:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeKVExternalSorter.<init>(UnsafeKVExternalSorter.java:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.destructAndCreateExternalSorter(UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.java:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/06/14 06:39:50 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 62.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/06/14 06:39:50 WARN BlockManager: Putting block rdd_300_15 failed due to an exception
17/06/14 06:39:50 WARN BlockManager: Block rdd_300_15 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
17/06/14 06:39:50 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 15.0 in stage 62.0 (TID 1997, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
17/06/14 06:39:50 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 12.0 in stage 62.0 (TID 1994, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 62.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 62.0 (TID 1982, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no space for new record
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeInMemorySorter.insertRecord(UnsafeInMemorySorter.java:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeKVExternalSorter.<init>(UnsafeKVExternalSorter.java:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.destructAndCreateExternalSorter(UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.java:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1920)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1933)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1946)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:604)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no space for new record
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeInMemorySorter.insertRecord(UnsafeInMemorySorter.java:225)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeKVExternalSorter.<init>(UnsafeKVExternalSorter.java:130)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.destructAndCreateExternalSorter(UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap.java:244)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea about that?
Or any parameter/memory management I can tune to tackle it? Thanks!
BTW, I'm using Spark-2.1.0.3

Comment: which version of spark are you using?... there is seems to be fix as per this issues in Spark 2.x as per this ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19500

Comment: @rogue-one I'm using 2.1.0.3,  it seems not fixed...

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this?  I'm running into the same issue

Comment: @mdeland Still no, I just go with the huge sql query which can work

Comment: Getting the same exception when I write a CSV file. Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running into an issue with the amount of RAM available on your executors.

It's perfectly understandable that the first command works without issue but the second does not: they are two different computations.

In the first, you are reading in the table to a DataFrame, with the number of partitions set by whatever default is used. Then, you're simply writing that same table to disk, which will create a separate file for each partition.

In the second, you're performing a `.groupBy` and an aggregation, which means that each reducer is being sent the keys from "colA" to aggregate. If these reducer tasks can't hold all the data they receive in memory, they'll spill to disk (as this error seems to suggest).

You can solve this problem by either allocating more memory for each executor, or by increasing the number of partitions used for the aggregation. The latter option is usually easier -- you just need to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to a larger number, and try your `.groupBy`/`agg` operation again. By default, `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is set to `200`, and for big tables, this is sometimes not enough to aggregate, which is why you're having this problem. As a start, try quadrupling the number of shuffle partitions by setting this param to `800`.